# Update TextView on timer tick in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have got trouble to update my TextView in tab fragment. I want to setText on TextView on every second with global variable data. This works fine in activity, but not in fragment. Error is: **textView2 cannot be resolved.** If there is better method for updating this, or is this isn't good, please tell me.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    //timer
        private TimerTask mTimerTask;
        private Timer timer = new Timer();  

        private final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);


        //TextView for Device name
        TextView textView3 = (TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
        //TextView for Serial number
        TextView textView5 = (TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.TextView5);
        //TextView for Software version
        TextView textView7 = (TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.TextView7);

        onTimerTick();
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 10, 1000); 

        return myFragmentView;
    }

        //timer tick on every 1 s 
        public void onTimerTick() {
            mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
                //this method is called every 1ms
                public void run() {                 
                     timerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {  
                            //update textView
                            //ERROR:textView2 cannot be resolved
                                textView2.setText(m_info.deviceName);
                            Log.d("tag", "Hello from timer fragment");
                         }
                     });                    
                }};      
        }             
}
```

Comment: Where is `textView2` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, TextView3 for example... textView3.setText(m_info.deviceName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

declare `textView3` as a field.
  TextView textView3;

And initialize it in the `onCreateView()`

```
textView3 = (TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
```

And also

initialize your Handler inside of `onCreateView`, so that it allow access to you UI.
do the same for Handler also

```
Handler timerHandler;
```

And in oncrateView

```
timerHandler=new Handler();
```

Comment: This works like a charm :) Do I need to stop timer, when tab is not selected onPause method? Because in debug I can see that timer runs even tab is not selected. Could this bi the problem?

Answer (score 0):

onTimerTick() should be in your MainActivity class;
then in your main activity class

```
TextView textViewForTimerTick=this.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);// id of a textView in your fragment;
```

that's all.

so :

```
class MainActivity{
private TextView tv2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle...){
.
.
setFragmentToContainer(new FragmentA);// i dont' know how you are setting up your fragment
.
.
tv2=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_view_in_fragment);// only after you'v set up your fragment
onTimerTick();
}

public void onTimerTick(){

.....

}


}
```